# Unit cube cut into two parts through its diagonals

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

**Question:**

> A cube having each side of unit length is cut into two parts by a plane through two diagonals of two opposite faces. What is the total surface area of each of these parts?

**My attempt:**

I am still unable to visualize the problem, let alone solve it! I have managed to solve similar problems involving spheres because visualizing spheres was easy but this is (very) tough.

Can someone please give starting hints?

**UPDATE:** I agree with Ross's answer, but it took me a whole while to visualize this thing. Now that *I* do visualize, it would be great if *everyone* like me could visualize.

I would wish if someone could please simply draw a diagram to illustrate the problem. I don't have sharp skills with 3D math geometry software otherwise I would do that myself.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?  Have you tried taking a cube (say, a die) and marking its outside with a marker to show where the cut goes?  Have you tried making a cube out of fruit and cutting it in the required way?

Comment: If you agree with my answer and it was useful, you should upvote it.  It came back because no answer had an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the cut is two right triangular prisms.  The base of each is a $1-1-\sqrt 2$ triangle (the result of cutting one face of the cube) and the height is $1$